# Aurelia + Whatwg-fetch: Call wrong API service

Tags: fetch, aurelia

I'm developing a web application with Aurelia. I had a problem with Aurelia and Whatwg-fetch.

The API's relative url is `api/post/load/{id}`. When I use the fetch client to call this API, I think it gets the current url to call (http://localhost:9000/detail/api/post/load/{id}). I don't know why it happens. Sometime it calls the API's url correctly, other times it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url at which you access your app is http://localhost:9000/details. Since you didn't include a hashmark (`#`) in it, I assume the `details` part is not added by Aurelia, which leads me to believe that you access the app itself at `/details`.

If that is the case, the problem is that by **not** prefixing your API's url with a slash (`/`), the resulting url will be base url+api url, that is, `localhost:9000/details` + `api/post/load/id`. The slash between `details` and `api` is added on your behalf while constucting the final absolute url. In this case, all you need to do is to prefix the api url with a slash, like so: `/api/post/load/{id}`.